# Was there a Collector's Edition of StarCraft or Brood War?

Tags: starcraft

Blizzard Entertainment historically has released Collector's Editions for most of their games going back to Diablo II, except for the Lord of Destruction and The Frozen Throne expansion packs. I've heard rumors that there was a CE for StarCraft 1 (but not Brood War), but searching the Internet only turns up page after page of non-discussion of the various SC2 collector's boxes.

**Was there a Collector's Edition produced at any point for either StarCraft 1 or Brood War?**

Comment: The fact that it doesn't turn up anywhere on any page (I searched too), would lead me to believe that there is no such edition for SC1 or BW.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I couldn't find any official mentions of it, I found multiple images, [eBay listings](http://r.ebay.com/p3Twax), and forum threads suggesting the existence of a non-US collector's edition. [This forum post](http://collectorsedition.org/forums/showpost.php?p=219363&postcount=3609) has photos of the contents of the aforementioned collector's edition.

[image: StarCraft Collector's Edition]

Comment: I believe their was a U.S. collector's edition, but I don't remember it having this cover. I want to say it came in an oddly shaped box that the sides angled up towards the top instead of being straight, then angled back out again.

Comment: @Powerlord : I would be happy to add the U.S. collector's edition to this answer as soon as a source supporting its existence can be provided.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that in the UK there was a collectors edition of Starcraft (I bought one). AFAIK there wasn't a collectors edition of Brood War.